# How to find that each student number belongs to unique student?

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, data-manipulation

I have a data frame and around 10-12 columns. One of the column is the student number e.g. 1234567 and the other is an identifier e.g passport numbers, license number . How can I find that each student has a unique identifier. Like student 1234567 has identifier ABC5679K only. Also I want to store the students who are tagged with duplicate identifier. For e.g. If student 1234567 also has identifier ABC3408T, I want to know those.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming such input, where  the first student has a unique other id, while the second has two different ids:

```
   student_id other_id
0           1        a
1           1        a
2           2        b
3           2        c
```

you can use `GroupBy.transform` with `nunique` for that:

```
mask = df.groupby('student_id')['other_id'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

print(df[mask])
```

output:

```
   student_id other_id
2           2        b
3           2        c
```

Or, for a list of all students with duplicated other ids:

```
s = df.groupby('student_id')['other_id'].nunique()
s[s>1].index.to_list()
```

output: `[2]`

Comment: May I know what is the difference between mask and s? I am new to python. I see mask is a series of True and False.  From my understanding s has group by and has given count of unique student id and other id combination. Any count >1 is not unique and will be added to the list and give list of not unique student ID. If I want to see what other_id values these duplicates have how can I see? I also want to see that 2 is taking values b and c.

Comment: both are Series and the names are just my personal choice. I generally use mask for a Series of booleans of the same size as the input. `s` is the aggregated version of `df.groupby('student_id')['other_id'].transform('nunique')` where you get only 1 row per student_id. If you want to see the duplicate values use the first option, no?

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby(["student_name"])["passport_number"].nunique() > 1`

You can use the groupby and nunique function to help you identify repeats. Hope this answer your question.